# Promise on service returning treated data for another promise on component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wonder if its possible to do like below, or even how should I can do it.
For those who ask why, its because I can guarantee in my service that the returned data will be treated and adjusted as myfile need..

Can you help? XD

**Scenary 01 == What I have ==**

**myFile.ts**

```
methodReturnPromise()
    .then( data => { /* Sucess, Do This */} )
    .catch( err => { /* Failure, Do This Instead */} );
```

**Scenary 02 == What I want ==**

***service.ts***

```
myServiceMethod(): Promise<any> {
    methodReturnPromise()
        .then( data => { /* Sucess, Treat and return */} )
        .catch( err => { /* Failure, Do This Instead and return */} );
}
```

***myFile.ts***

```
this.myService.myServiceMethod()
    .then( data => { /* Success, Do this */})
    .catch( err => { /* Failure, Do This Instead */} );
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  Are you asking whether it's possible to write multiple functions that return promises?

Comment: you're missing a return `myServiceMethod(): Promise<any> {
    return methodReturnPromise()`

Comment: sorry @SLaks wich edition would you suggest? I'm starting my studies and somethings are still unknown for me

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, but left it on purpose cause I don't know how to do it properly...

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: If you expect a function to return a promise then return a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `then` and `catch` multiple times. So change the `myServiceMethod()` for something like this:

```
myServiceMethod(): Promise<any> {
    return methodReturnPromise()
        .then( data => { 
            /* Success, do something here and return the same data received */ 
            return data; 
         } )
        .catch( err => { 
            /* Failure, do something here and rethrow the same error */

            throw err;
        } );
}
```

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("ok");
});

promise1.then(function(data) {
    console.log("log1", data);
    return data;
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("log2", data);
  });

var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject("ERROR");
});

promise2.catch(function(err) {
    console.error("error1", err);
    throw err;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error("error2", err);
  });
```